# Is this a common scolding expression "Your night is dark, just wait for me till we back home."

Tags: expressions, vocabulary, collocations

I was watching a video about scolding in English and one of the expressions the instructor in the video said was this:

> Your night is dark,  just wait for me till we back home.

This sentence makes perfect sense in arabic, the native language of the teacher in the video. But I've never heard any native English speaker say it before.

Its meaning in arabic should be equivalent to this.

Your night is dark: your day (not necessary the child's night) isn't going to be good because of what you did aka you'll be scolded, punished, grounded, etc.

Just wait for me: in arabic the verb 'wait' can also be used to say 'give me some time' or 'be patient with me' and may be used before a thread as if to say 'give me some time then you'll see what I'll do to you'. I've just checked the dictionary and I don't think 'wait' is used in the same way in English.

For 'we back home' part. I've no idea why verb To be is omitted, I guess to make it sound informal.

Writing the question down, I come to realize there's a very great likelihood the sentence is wrong but the guy in the video has a very good accent and the rest of the phrases or words he said were all right so I've some hope this expression is actually used.

The video link (note: not all English): https://fb.watch/1EFCl81bVx/

Comment: No, it is not at all idiomatic in English. A parent might say to a misbehaving child "Just you wait till we get home!", but there is no English equivalent to the Arabic "Your night is dark" as you explain it.

Comment: But *the guy in the video has a **terrible** accent!* And this specific example isn't the only "poor phrasing". Ignore him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a common or correct expression.

"Your night is dark": This is not something I have ever heard before and searching on Google brings up 0 relevant responses. It is grammatically correct and I could see it being used if there was some other information/reference/inside joke to provide context. To me, it sounds overly cryptic or mysterious and a very strange way to scold/threaten someone.

"just wait for me": We would use the verb 'to wait' similarly to this but it would be constructed differently. For scolding purposes, we wouldn't use "wait for me". More common is "just wait" or "just you wait". Adding the 'you' is a strange construction that I can't think of many examples that use other verbs but it is common for 'just you wait'. "Just you wait" is stronger and more threatening than 'just wait'.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/just-you-wait

"Just you wait" is a phrase that the connotation can change dramatically with the tone of voice which it is said so it may be a good idea to look up a video with it if you're unsure.

"till we back home": This is not correct. The sentence is already made informal by changing 'until' for 'till'. It is not correct to drop the verb here. It should be "till we get(/are) back home"

Putting these together: "Just (you) wait till we get back home". This is a common thing for someone to say to warn someone that they have done something bad and will be punished when they get home.

Comment: The nearest English equivalent to *Your night is dark* might perhaps be ***You're for it! / You'll be in for it tonight!***